# Did Yama and Shani ever confront each other?

Tags: yama, shani

As Yama and Shani are brothers and even have similar kind of work (to judge our karmas), did they ever confront each other while performing their duties? Is any such event explained in our scriptures?

Answer (score 1):

Both *Yama* and *Shani* have different works to do. *Yama* judges our karmas, while *Shani* counts them. Each intake and outtake of air inside our body is considered to count *Ayu* of a living creature, and this counting is done by *Shani mahadev*.

I heard this from an episode published in *TTD* channel (but I don't remember when).

*Shani* has two sons who will take care of every karma (both good and bad, I guess one son documents good and another bad) of every living creature and record is submitted to *Chitragupta* in *Yamaloka*. *Chitrgupta* will announce good and bad karmas of all souls who enters the *Yamaloka* and *Yamadharmaraya* decides to punish or send to *Swargaloka*.

Comment: Can you please explain __"Shani Mahadev"__?